# Google SignIn Integration Issue

Tags: ios, swift, integration, google-signin

I tried to implement in my code. How will I go to another controller when user complete it's signIn process. But I did't get any perfect solution on Google. What can I do for that type of issue . if you have any suggestion for me please help.

This is `ViewController.swift` code I put all code step by step.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnOutLet: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "KEY"

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self 
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        else
        {
            print(user.profile.email)
            //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: self)
        } 
    }

    @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) { 
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()  
    }

}
```

This is `Appdelegate` code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMainclass AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue your are facing?

Comment: @Kuldeep Actually I want to go another controller when user complete its signin. How can I do that?

Comment: uncomment `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: self)` and add `identifier`.

Comment: @Kuldeep I uncomment it. But When I am clicking on SignIn Button. It's going another controller before the signin. And I want after signIn.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if error == nil
    {

        print(user.profile.email)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.35) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "youridentifier", sender: self)
        }


    }
    else
    {
        print(error)
    }
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I am trying this code but it is now working properly. When I am clicking on SignIn Button. It's going another controller before the signin. And I want after signIn.

Comment: if call this func `didSignInFor` before sign in please make sure user logout

Comment: I am running on new device and the user not logged in that device. Still that same problem.

Comment: @VeerendraPratapsingh , Edit the answer Try it now I'm sure it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

After the user sign in and your app get the needed information you can use:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.viewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

its one of GIDSignInUIDelegate, after the user sign, it will work, for that you can use it to navigate to any view controller.